# Duplicates of categories in While-loop for posts

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, categories, array-filter

I don't have want to find out a bug or anything, I'm just bad at coding.

What have have is this code, to find my categories in the fourth level, and print out the descriptions:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : 
        the_post();
        $array = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_category' );
        $fourth_level = array_filter($array, function ($t) {        
            if($t->parent != 0 
                && get_term($t->parent, 'product_category')->parent  != 0
                && get_term(get_term($t->parent, 'product_category')->parent, 'product_category')->parent != 0
                && get_term(get_term(get_term($t->parent, 'product_category')->parent, 'product_category')->parent, 'product_category')->parent == 0) return true;
            else return false;
        });

        foreach($fourth_level as $company)
        {
            if(isset($company))
            {
                // Print out company info \\
                echo "<a href='http://stilius.se/wilink/store/products/category/" . $company->slug . "/?cat=" . $_GET["cat"] . "'>" . $company->description . "</a>";
            }
        }
```

The problem with the code is this: Every time a category (company) has more than one post (product) the code prints out multiple category descriptions.

Would there be an easy way to just check if the category description is already printed out and then prevent the printing of said category, or check if a there are multiple posts in the same category and then only print it once?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in your select query use group by

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for bothering you, just one question: Exactly where in the query would i put the GROUP BY?

Comment: select * from <tablename> group by <fieldname>

Comment: What you're trying to do , the way you're trying to do seems like a bad practice. Can you please share with us the `database logic` and what exactly you're trying to achieve? I'm sure that there's a better way of achieving what you're willing to.

Comment: So,        

$array = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), GROUP BY 'product_category' );

?

Comment: Well, I have never actually modified the database via MySQL, all I have done is used the standard Wordpress functions. Therefore I am very unsure how to use such commands.

Comment: The WP_Query loop(The whole while function) that collects the posts from the database is something I am unfamiliar with. I do not know where not put the group by command, could someone please help?